# Search data in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am displaying a list of items from sqlite. Now, on click of an item, I want to show its description in dialog box.

How can I get the text of the selected item, then search it in sqlite database & return the description contained in that row.

I hope my problem is  clear, How should I code ?

Thanks in advance...

```
public class SampleAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private final Context mContext;
private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

private final String[] mGroups = {
        "PART I",
        "PART II",
        "PART III",
        "PART IV",
        "PART IVA",
        "PART V",
        "PART VI",
        "PART VII",
        "PART VIII",
        "PART IX",
        "PART IXA",
        "PART X",
        "PART XI",
        "PART XII",
        "PART XIII",
        "PART XIV",
        "PART XIVA",
        "PART XV",
        "PART XVI",
        "PART XVII",
        "PART XVIII",
        "PART XIX",
        "PART XX",
        "PART XXI",
        "PART XXII"
};



private final String[][] mChilds = {
        {
            S.q.get(0).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(0).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(1).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(2).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(3).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(4).getAS_name()
        },
        {
            S.q.get(5).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(5).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(6).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(7).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(8).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(9).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(10).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(11).getAS_name()
        },
        {
            S.q.get(12).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(12).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(12).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(13).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(14).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(14).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(15).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(16).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(17).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(18).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(19).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(19).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(20).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(21).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(22).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(23).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(24).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(24).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(25).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(26).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(26).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(27).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(28).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(29).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(30).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(30).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(31).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(32).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(33).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(33).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(34).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(35).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(459).getAS_name(),

            S.q.get(36).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(36).getAS_name(),           
            S.q.get(37).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(38).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(39).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(40).getAS_name(),
        },
        {
            S.q.get(41).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(42).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(43).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(44).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(45).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(46).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(47).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(48).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(49).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(50).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(51).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(52).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(53).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(54).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(55).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(56).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(57).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(58).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(59).getAS_name(),
        },
        {
            S.q.get(60).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(60).getAS_name()
        },
        {
            S.q.get(61).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(61).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(62).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(63).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(64).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(65).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(66).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(67).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(68).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(69).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(70).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(71).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(72).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(73).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(74).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(75).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(76).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(77).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(78).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(79).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(80).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(81).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(82).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(83).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(83).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(84).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(85).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(85).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(86).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(86).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(87).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(88).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(88).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(88).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(89).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(90).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(91).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(92).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(93).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(94).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(95).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(96).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(97).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(98).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(98).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(99).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(100).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(101).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(102).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(103).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(104).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(105).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(106).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(107).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(108).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(108).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(109).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(110).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(110).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(111).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(112).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(113).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(114).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(114).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(115).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(116).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(117).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(118).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(119).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(120).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(121).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(121).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(122).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(123).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(124).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(125).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(126).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(127).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(127).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(128).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(129).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(130).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(131).getAS_name(),

            S.q.get(132).getA_name(),

            S.q.get(132).getAS_name(),

            S.q.get(133).getA_name(),

            S.q.get(133).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(134).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(135).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(136).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(137).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(138).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(139).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(140).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(141).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(142).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(143).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(144).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(145).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(146).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(147).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(148).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(149).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(150).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(151).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(152).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(153).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(154).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(155).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(156).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(157).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(460).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(461).getAS_name(),

            S.q.get(158).getAS_name(),

            S.q.get(159).getA_name(),

            S.q.get(159).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(160).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(161).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(162).getAS_name(),


        },
        {
            S.q.get(163).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(163).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(164).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(164).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(164).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(165).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(166).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(167).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(168).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(169).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(170).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(171).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(172).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(173).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(173).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(174).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(175).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(175).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(176).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(176).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(177).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(178).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(178).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(178).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(179).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(180).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(181).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(182).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(183).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(184).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(185).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(186).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(187).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(188).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(189).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(190).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(191).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(192).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(193).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(194).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(195).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(196).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(197).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(198).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(199).getAS_name(),

            S.q.get(200).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(200).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(201).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(202).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(203).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(204).getExtra(),

            S.q.get(204).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(205).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(206).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(206).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(207).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(208).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(209).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(462).getAS_name(),

            S.q.get(210).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(211).getExtra(),

            S.q.get(211).getAS_name(),

            S.q.get(212).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(213).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(214).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(215).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(216).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(217).getExtra(),

            S.q.get(217).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(463).getAS_name(),

            S.q.get(218).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(219).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(220).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(221).getA_name(),

            S.q.get(221).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(222).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(222).getAS_name(),

            S.q.get(223).getAS_name(),


            S.q.get(224).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(225).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(226).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(227).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(228).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(229).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(230).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(231).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(232).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(233).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(234).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(235).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(236).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(237).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(238).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(239).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(240).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(241).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(242).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(243).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(464).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(243).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(244).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(245).getAS_name(),          
            S.q.get(246).getAS_name(),          
            S.q.get(247).getAS_name(),









        },
        {
            S.q.get(248).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(248).getAS_name(),
        },

        {
            S.q.get(249).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(249).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(250).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(251).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(252).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(253).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(254).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(255).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(256).getAS_name(),  
        },

        {//IX
            S.q.get(257).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(257).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(258).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(259).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(260).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(261).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(262).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(263).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(264).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(265).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(266).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(267).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(268).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(269).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(270).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(271).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(272).getAS_name(),


        },


        {//IXA
            S.q.get(273).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(273).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(274).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(275).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(276).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(277).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(278).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(279).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(280).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(281).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(282).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(283).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(284).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(285).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(286).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(287).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(288).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(289).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(290).getAS_name(),

        },

        {//X
            S.q.get(291).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(291).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(292).getAS_name(),
        },

        {//XI
            S.q.get(293).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(293).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(293).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(294).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(295).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(296).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(297).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(298).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(299).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(300).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(301).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(302).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(303).getAS_name(),

            S.q.get(304).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(304).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(304).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(305).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(306).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(307).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(308).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(309).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(310).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(311).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(312).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(312).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(313).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(313).getAS_name(),
        },
        {// XII
            S.q.get(314).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(314).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(314).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(315).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(316).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(317).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(318).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(318).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(319).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(320).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(321).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(322).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(323).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(324).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(325).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(326).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(327).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(328).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(329).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(330).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(331).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(332).getExtra(),
            S.q.get(332).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(333 ).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(334).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(335).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(336).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(337).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(338).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(339).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(340).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(341).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(342).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(343).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(343).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(344).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(345).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(345).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(346).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(347).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(348).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(349).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(350).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(351).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(352).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(352).getAS_name(),


        },
        {//XIII
            S.q.get(353).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(353).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(354).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(355).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(356).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(357).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(358).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(359).getAS_name(),
        },
        {//XIV
            S.q.get(360).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(360).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(361).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(362).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(363).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(364).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(364).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(365).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(366).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(367).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(368).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(368).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(369).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(370).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(371).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(372).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(373).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(374).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(375).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(376).getAS_name(),

        },
        {//XIVA
            S.q.get(377).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(377).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(378).getAS_name(),
        },
        {//XV
            S.q.get(379).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(379).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(380).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(381).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(382).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(383).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(384).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(385).getAS_name(),
        },
        {//XVI
            S.q.get(386).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(386).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(387).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(388).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(389).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(390).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(391).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(392).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(393).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(394).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(395).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(396).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(397).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(398).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(399).getAS_name(),


        },
        {//xvii
            S.q.get(400).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(400).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(401).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(402).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(402).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(403).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(404).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(405).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(405).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(406).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(407).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(407).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(408).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(409).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(410).getAS_name(),

        },

        {//xviii
            S.q.get(411).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(411).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(412).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(413).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(414).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(415).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(416).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(417).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(418).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(419).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(420).getAS_name(),
        },

        {
            S.q.get(421).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(421).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(422).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(423).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(424).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(425).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(426).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(427).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(428).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(429).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(430).getAS_name(),

        },

        {//XX
            S.q.get(431).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(431).getAS_name(),
        },
        {
            S.q.get(432).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(432).getAS_name(),

            S.q.get(433).getAS_name(),

            S.q.get(434).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(435).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(436).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(437).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(438).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(439).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(440).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(441).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(442).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(443).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(444).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(445).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(446).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(447).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(448).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(449).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(450).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(451).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(452).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(453).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(454).getAS_name()
        },
        {
            S.q.get(455).getA_name(),
            S.q.get(455).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(456).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(457).getAS_name(),
            S.q.get(458).getAS_name()
        }

};

public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return mGroups.length;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return mGroups[groupPosition];
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_activity_list_group_item, parent, false);
    }

    final TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sample_activity_list_group_item_text);
    text.setText( mGroups[groupPosition]);

    final ImageView expandedImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sample_activity_list_group_expanded_image);
    final int resId = isExpanded ? R.drawable.minus : R.drawable.plus;
    expandedImage.setImageResource(resId);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return mChilds[groupPosition].length;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return mChilds[groupPosition][childPosition];
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int type;
    TextView text = null;
    if(convertView == null) {
        if(mChilds[groupPosition][childPosition].substring(0,1).matches("[0-9]"))
        {
            type =0;
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_activity_list_child_item, parent, false);
             text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sample_activity_list_child_item_text);
        }
        else if(mChilds[groupPosition][childPosition].substring(1, 2).matches("[A-Z]"))
        {
            type = 1;
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.black_layout, parent, false);
            text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.black_textView);
        }
        else 
        {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gray_layout, parent, false);
            text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            type =2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(mChilds[groupPosition][childPosition].substring(0,1).matches("[0-9]"))
        {
            type =0;
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_activity_list_child_item, parent, false);
             text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sample_activity_list_child_item_text);
        }
        else if(mChilds[groupPosition][childPosition].substring(1, 2).matches("[A-Z]"))
        {
            type = 1;
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.black_layout, parent, false);
            text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.black_textView);
        }
        else
        {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gray_layout, parent, false);
            text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            type =2;
        }
    }

    // text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sample_activity_list_child_item_text);
    text.setText(mChilds[groupPosition][childPosition]);
    text.setOnClickListener(null);

    if(type ==0)
    text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.description);

            TextView desc = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView3);//desc
            TextView part = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView italic = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

            italic.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
            title.setText(S.q.get(childPosition).getAS_name());
            desc.setText(S.q.get(childPosition).getDesc_art());
            part.setText(S.q.get(childPosition).getPart());
            italic.setText(S.q.get(childPosition).getItalic());

 dialog.show();
 dialog.setCancelable(true);
 dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);    

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: what is the list adapter you are using? custom adapter or not?

Comment: it extends BaseExpandableListAdapter from FloatingGroupExpandableListView, I cannot use this by content wrapper

Comment: have u tried anything??

Comment: Ya,I have the data in arraylist

Comment: I added my code in the question, this is how I my listview looks , in the getChildView I have the onClickListenter which is showing wrong values

Comment: are u using getChild method? u can get current selected item position from listView, or u can set the itemId to the convertView tag(listItem in listView) then in onClick(for ex) get the view tag and search db for selectedItemId

Comment: Cant I search in  the db using the text which is clicked ?

Comment: yes u can search db with text or other dataType, but it most unique if u want see only one row in query result

Comment: All rows are unique & I want to return only 1 row !

Comment: Dumping all that code there is a sign of lack of respect for thecommunity. Please only post a minimal example

Comment: I post a minimal example on this question , please have a look, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584122/getting-a-unique-row-in-sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is simple way to get the selected dataRow from ListView
in your getView or getChildView method after set all data to view, set dataKey to the convert view Tag, so you can get the info later by this tag

> convertView.setTag(S.q.get(childPosition).getAS_name());

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ....

    // setTag Section that should add to your code
    convertView.setTag(S.q.get(childPosition).getAS_name());


    return convertView;
}
```

then set onItemClickListener for your listView

```
private OnItemClickListener ListViewOnItemClick = new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                long id)
        {
            try
            {
                Object t = ((ViewGroup) v).getChildAt(0).getTag();
                String st = t.toString();

                // Query db With This string (st) and ....

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

is that clear and helpful ?