# Getting a unique row in SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to search an item in sqlite by using String, & trying to return description contained in that row. items are stored in the table named `Articles` with column name `A_name`, Description column name is `AS_name`

This is my code, the cursor is not null, but the while loop is not getting executed once

```
public String searchData(String text)
{
    Cursor cursor = sdb.query("Articles", new String[] {"A_name","AS_name"}, " A_name=?",new String[]{text}, null, null, null);

     Log.e("running", "cursor run");


     String temp = null,temp2 = null;
     if(cursor!=null)
     {

         Log.e("running", "curosr is not null");
     while(cursor.moveToFirst())
     {

         Log.e("running", "curosr while loop enter");

          temp =  (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("A_name")));
          //temp2 =(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("AS_name")));
        Log.e("running", "id  email" +temp+ " name"+temp2);

    }
 }
     return temp;
}
```

I want to return the corresponding element of `AS_name`, also I am confused what should  I wrote in while loop ?

Can anyone please identify my mistake, Thanks in advance...

UPDATE **DBAdapter.java**

```
public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
//CustomAdapter adapter;
static String name = "law6.sqlite";
static String path = "";
static ArrayList<GS> gs;
static SQLiteDatabase sdb;

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
} 

private DBAdapter(Context v) 
{
    super(v, name, null, 1);
    path = "/data/data/" + v.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/databases";
}

public boolean checkDatabase()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try 
    {
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path + "/" + name, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (db == null) 
    {
        return false;
    } 
    else
    {
        db.close();
        return true;
    }
}

public static synchronized DBAdapter getDBAdapter(Context v)
{
    return (new DBAdapter(v));
}

public void createDatabase(Context v) 
{
    this.getReadableDatabase();
    try
    {
        InputStream myInput = v.getAssets().open(name);
        // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = path +"/"+ name;
        // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) 
    {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
        // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

    /*  



        InputStream is = v.getAssets().open("quiz.sqlite");
        // System.out.println(is.available());
        System.out.println(new File(path + "/" + name).getAbsolutePath());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + "/" + name);
        int num = 0;
        while ((num = is.read()) > 0) {
            fos.write((byte) num);
        }
        fos.close();
        is.close();*/
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void openDatabase() 
{
    try 
    {
        sdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path + "/" + name, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public ArrayList<GS> getData() 
{
    try{
    Cursor c1 = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Articles", null);
    gs = new ArrayList<GS>();
    while (c1.moveToNext())
    {
        GS q1 = new GS();
        q1.setId(c1.getString(0));
        q1.setA_id(c1.getString(1));
        q1.setA_name(c1.getString(2));
        q1.setAS_name(c1.getString(3));
        q1.setDesc_art(c1.getString(4));
    //  q1.setAct(c1.getString(5));
        q1.setExtra(c1.getString(6));
        q1.setPart(c1.getString(7));
        q1.setItalic(c1.getString(8));
        Log.v("AS_name",q1.AS_name);
        gs.add(q1);
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return gs;
}

public String searchData(String text)
{
    Cursor cursor = sdb.query("Articles", new String[] {"A_name","AS_name"}, " A_name=?",new String[]{text}, null, null, null);

     Log.e("running", "cursor run");


     String temp = null,temp2 = null;
     if(cursor!=null)
     {

         Log.e("running", "curosr is not null");
        Log.v("", ""+cursor.getCount());
     while(cursor.moveToNext())
     {

         Log.e("running", "curosr while loop enter");

          temp =  (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("AS_name")));
         // temp2 =(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(name)));
        Log.e("running", "desc" +temp);

    }
 }
     return temp;
}
}
```

UPDATE after implementing rajaji answer, I got this error :
[image]

Comment: change `cursor.moveToFirst()` to `cursor.moveToNext()` in while statement

Comment: Ya I tried this also but noting happened

Comment: check size of `cursor`, `cursor.getCount();` must be return `0`

Comment: yes cursor.getCount() is returning 0

Comment: Do you have a `UriMatcher` in your `ContentProvider`?

Comment: I dont have UriMatcher , plese see my DBAdapter.java  in my edit

Comment: so while loop not getting executed, check `text`, are you sure that `text` values is exists on Database?

Comment: Text contains values & it exists in column "A_name"

Comment: check your Cursor by calling DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it will help you

create the raw query for getting the data

```
public String searchData(String text)
{
String strvalue=null;
SQliteDatabase db=this.getwritabledatabase();
Cursor cur=null;
String strquery="select * from youurtablename where A_name="+text;
cur=db.rawQuery(strquery,null); 
if(cur!=null&&cur.moveToFirst())
{
do
            {
                strvalue=cur.getString(0);
            }
            while(cur.moveToNext());
}  
}
```

let me inform once you complete

Comment: Error : No such column : text

Comment: try and let me inform

Comment: that text means your method parameter value, have you used your parameter value or "text"this value

Comment: it seems that it have some problem with the string got in 'text', because every string is starting with a number followed by a character then full stop , & then the data.  I gives the error of unrecognised token

Comment: post your text parameter value, and in that value which one is you nedd tell me

Comment: Please look at my updated question, I have posted the error in logcat

Comment: oh such a small error look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611805/return-the-searched-data-from-sqlite

Comment: @Enthusiast i didnot mind about single quote so thats why,i post answer like that any way you achieve your goal, i'll happy dude,and thanks for upvote and acceptable answer                         update this line                                               String strquery="select * from youurtablename where A_name='"+text+"'"; instead of this line in my program         String strquery="select * from youurtablename where A_name="+text;

Answer (score 0):

Is your Uri correct??

create Uri depends on your package name and table name, like the code below :

```
    private static final String AUTHORITY           = "com.sample.test_db_provider";
    private static final String BASE_PATH           = "Tables";
    private static final Uri    Sample_URI  = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
                                                        + "/" + BASE_PATH
                                                        + "/SampleTable");
```

Then in your get Method, query the db like the below code with Uri

```
cur = m_Resolver.query(Sample_URI, new String[] {"A_name","AS_name"},
                    "SampleTable.A_name = " + text, null, null);
            if(cur != null && cur.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    ...
                }
                while(cur.moveToNext());
            }
            cur.close();
```

I use the inline where clause but you can do it your way with a parameter.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I am getting this error in the query `The method query(String, String[], String, String[], String, String, String) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (Uri, String[], String, null, null)`

Comment: i use contentResolver and u use sqliteDataBase object directly, see this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html#sqliteoverview_sqliteopenhelper ,  implement contentProvider by yourSelf is good practice for oop and more flexible to future change