# Return the searched data from sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to search an item in sqlite by using String, & trying to return description contained in that row. items are stored in the table named `Articles` with column name `AS_name`, & the description column name is `Desc_art` which I am unable to return.

This is my code:

```
public String searchData(String item) {
    String strvalue = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = null;
    String strquery = "select * from Articles where AS_name = "+item;
    cur = db.rawQuery(strquery,null); 
    if(cur! = null&&cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            strvalue = cur.getString(0);
        } while(cur.moveToNext());
    }
    return strvalue;  
}
```

This is the error which I am getting:

[image]

I am confused please help..

Comment: Can u please update some other detailed code?? @Enthusiast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query `item` is  string,So change

```
String strquery="select * from Articles where AS_name= "+item;
```

to

```
String strquery="select * from Articles where AS_name='" + item + "'";
```

Or this

```
Cursor cur=null;
cur = db.query("Articles", null, "AS_name" + "=?",
            new String[] { item }, null, null, null, null);
```

instead of

```
Cursor cur=null;
String strquery="select * from Articles where AS_name= "+item;
cur=db.rawQuery(strquery,null);
```

And change

```
strvalue=cur.getString(0);
```

to

```
strvalue=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Desc_art"));
```

Comment: If you show the recommended parameterized query solution, I will upvote :) Otherwise this is correct but a not recommended way to query.

Comment: @Enthusiast you should try to use `cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Desc_art"));` to get the description. - Thanks for updating, Giru!

Comment: @Enthusiast to get Desc_art value,do as WarrenFaith suggested.see edited answer.

Comment: @Enthusiast Happy to help,enjoy coding.

Comment: Sir, can you please answer my [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799182/conversion-to-recommended-parametrized-query-method) ???

Answer (score 0):

1. add quotes to item:  `"select * from Articles where AS_name= '" + item + "'";`
2. And try to uninstall and reinstall app. If you made changes to the tables you need to uninstall and do a clean install.

> Thank you, the app is not crashing , but it is returning the indexing based on 1 , not the description contained in column named Desc_art, can you help me further

What column are you trying to return here in position 0 from the table?

```
strvalue=cur.getString(0);
```