# Conversion to recommended parametrized query method

Tags: java, android, database

For getting data from database I use raw query, as you can see

```
public ArrayList<GS> getSchedules() 
{
    try{
    Cursor c1 = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Schedules", null);
    gs = new ArrayList<GS>();
    while (c1.moveToNext())
    {
        GS q1 = new GS();
        q1.setS_name(c1.getString(1));
        q1.setP_name(c1.getString(2));
        q1.setDesc(c1.getString(3));
        gs.add(q1);
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return gs;
}
```

This method works successfullly but I want to change it to attain the recommended parametrized query method ?

Sorry if my question does not show any research effort, but I have tried & but I was lost.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: There are no parameters in your query so you already have a parameterized form with 0 params.

Comment: this type of query `query(distinct, table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit, cancellationSignal)`

Comment: While there are no parameters, its generally more efficient for the db to replace the * with the names of the columns you actually need.  That way it doesn't need to pack up the extras.

Comment: but using `rawQuery` is discouraged , we should use `query(distinct, table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit, cancellationSignal)` something like that ....

Comment: Why would anyone recommend using that over something simpler, more efficient and already working?

Comment: No, It wont work for me in android 2.2 version

Comment: Using a helper method that just builds the same SQL string and prepares it with `rawQuery()` won't solve the problem. If you have a specific problem with 2.2, please post it in the question.

Comment: in 2.2 it says no such table , but working fine in newer versions

Comment: @vwvwvwvwvwvwvwvwvw As laalto and Gabe Sechan are right,and for parameterized query see below answer.

Comment: @vwvwvwvwvwvwvwvwvw and also check if it is working on 2.2 or not.

Comment: After Giru bhai answer it still not works in 2.2, i have posted another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808837/error-no-such-table-in-api-2-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid use of `rawQuery` whenever possible... always prefer the built in `SQLiteDatabase` query methods over `rawQuery`.

So you may use this method

```
public Cursor query (boolean distinct, String table, 
                         String[] columns, String selection, 
                         String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, 
                         String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

So change

```
Cursor c1 = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Schedules", null);
```

to

```
Cursor c1 = sdb.query(true,"Schedules",null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
```

For more info see [Android sqlite query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Note : As @Gabe Sechan suggested,in DISTINCT  its generally more efficient for the db to **replace the * with the names of the columns** you actually need.

Comment: And downvoters please comment the reason if you downvote.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, It Works but Not working in 2.2 ! I have  posted another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808837/error-no-such-table-in-api-2-2